# What is Channeling in MiniZinc? Can you provide an simple example to explain Channeling? Finally, What is Inverse?

Tags: minizinc

What is Channeling in MiniZinc? Can you provide an simple example to explain Channeling? Finally, What is Inverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are used to establish a bidirectional relationship between two arrays.

Let `f` be an array with `index_set(f)` equal to `1..10` and values in `81..90`.
Then `f` can be seen as a mapping *--a.k.a. a function--* from the set of values `1..10` to the set of values `81..90`.

**Inverse**.

```
predicate inverse(array [int] of var int: f,
                  array [int] of var int: invf)
```

This constraint says that if `f` is a function mapping an index `i` to a value `j`, then `invf` is a function mapping an index `j` to a value `i` (and vice-versa). In other words, the array `invf` is indexed with the values in `f` and it yields the position in `f` of the each value contained in `f`.

**int_set_channel**.

```
predicate int_set_channel(array [int] of var int: x,
                          array [int] of var set of int: y)
```

The constraint says that if `x` is a function mapping an index `i` to a given set `j`, then the value `i` is contained in the set at index `j` in `y` (and vice-versa). This is the exact same thing as the *inverse* constraint, only that `y` is an array of sets rather than an array of values.

---

In my experience, *chanelling constraints* are useful to move from one *problem view* to another, so as to express other constraints in the most natural *--and efficient--* way. This type of constraints may use the global constraints described above, or expressed using basic language constructs. See, for instance, [carseq.mzn](https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks/blob/master/carseq/carseq.mzn).

For more useful information and a concrete example, see [**Section 2.6.6.1 of the docs**](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.1/en/efficient.html#sec-multiple-modelling-and-channels).

---

[**Example**](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.1/en/downloads/nqueens_sym.mzn):

```
int: n;
array [1..n] of var 1..n: q; % queen is column i is in row q[i]

include "alldifferent.mzn";

constraint alldifferent(q);                       % distinct rows
constraint alldifferent([ q[i] + i | i in 1..n]); % distinct diagonals
constraint alldifferent([ q[i] - i | i in 1..n]); % upwards+downwards

include "lex_lesseq.mzn";

% Alternative Boolean model:
% Map each position i,j to a Boolean telling us whether there is a queen at i,j
array[1..n,1..n] of var bool: qb;

% Channeling constraint
constraint forall (i,j in 1..n) ( qb[i,j] <-> (q[i]=j) );

% Lexicographic symmetry breaking constraints
constraint
    lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[j,i] | i,j in 1..n ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[i,j] | i in reverse(1..n), j in 1..n ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[j,i] | i in 1..n, j in reverse(1..n) ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[i,j] | i in 1..n, j in reverse(1..n) ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[j,i] | i in reverse(1..n), j in 1..n ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[i,j] | i,j in reverse(1..n) ])
/\  lex_lesseq(array1d(qb), [ qb[j,i] | i,j in reverse(1..n) ])
;

% search
solve :: int_search(q, first_fail, indomain_min)
      satisfy;
output [ if fix(q[j]) == i then "Q" else "." endif ++
         if j == n then "\n" else "" endif | i,j in 1..n]
```

Here, the *channeling constraints* put in relation the two views of the **n-queens** problem contained in the model. The first view `q` is uni-dimensional, and tells the row position of the queen within each column. The second view `qb` is bi-dimensional, and tells which tile of the chessboard is occupied by some queen. The first view is great for solving the *placement* part of the problem. the second view is great for applying *symmetry breaking constraints*.